# Component accepts `renderAs` and should accept any of its props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component [`Button`](https://github.com/dfee/react-bulma-components/blob/master/src/components/button/button.js) that takes a prop `renderAs`.

For example, I want to render it as a `Link` from `react-router-dom`, but the `Button` doesn't accept the props that `Link` accepts.

Generically, how could I get the Button to allow all props that the component defined in `renderAs` accepts?

[Here is a link](https://github.com/dfee/react-bulma-components/blob/63e718337b0501f9d109829954941fd2448eae68/index.d.ts#L160) in my declaration file to the `Button` type.

**Code:**

`Button` is a simple function that renders an `Element`, and the `Element` looks like this:

```
const Element = React.forwardRef(({
  className,
  renderAs,
  ...allProps
}, ref) => {
  const RenderAs = renderAs;
  const props = modifiers.clean(allProps);
  return (
    <RenderAs
      ref={ref}
      className={classnames(className, modifiers.classnames(allProps)) || undefined}
      {...props}
    />
  );
});
```

(the question can then be assumed to be: how can I get an `Element` to take any props that the component to `renderAs` accepts?)

The (relevant) interface for `Element` in my declaration file looks like this:

```
interface ElementProps
  extends Partial<
    React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements>
  > {
  className?: string;
  renderAs?: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements | React.ComponentType<any>;
  // [key: string]: any; // former attempt; but disables all prop checking
}
declare const Element: React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<
  React.PropsWithoutRef<ElementProps> & React.RefAttributes<any>
>;
```

Comment: Consider providing all relevant code in the question. It should be understandable without visiting off-site resources. Links may become broken.

Comment: @estus updated to show code samples. thanks!

Comment: @Devin - did you figure out how to do this? I'm in the same situation now, and I would really like to get properly extended prop types for my own Button.